# LNK Errors when using MSVC2017 (amd64) compiler in Qt Creator 4.5.0 (Qt 5.10.0)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I have a Qt project that fails to compile with the MSVC2017 compiler in Qt Creator due to LNK errors (4099, 4098, 2001, and 2019). The issues appear to arise from my inclusion of 3rd party libraries. I am using "QCustomPlot" (as .h and .cpp files, *I am not using a .dll and the QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_LIBRARY define*) and it works great when I'm compiling in Qt Creator with the *MinGW kit*. I am also using "libMPSSE" (as .h and .lib files) and this library works great when compiling in *visual studio 2017*.

I believe that I'm missing a step here as far as setting up Qt Creator with the MSVC2017 compiler. Here are snippets from the top and bottom of my error list (disregard the first warning, I commented out the section where the variable is used):

error list 1

[image]

~~~

error list 2

[image]

Here is what my build settings look like for the project (I haven't manually changed anything here):

build settings

[image]

Here is what my kit setup looks like:

kit settings

[image]

And here is what my .pro file looks like:

```
QT       += core \
            gui \
            printsupport

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MotionDetection
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
INCLUDEPATH += -L"(.lib directory location)"

LIBS += -lKernel32
LIBS += -L"(.lib directory location)" -llibMPSSE

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    datacapture.cpp \
    mdinterface.cpp \
    mdata.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    datacapture.h \
    mdinterface.h \
    mdata.h \
    qcustomplot.h \
    ftd2xx.h \
    libMPSSE_spi.h \

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

*I should also note -- I have deleted everything in my build folder, and then ran 'clean project', 'qmake', and 'build'. In my build folder, there is indeed a 'moc' file for qcustomplot.

Comment: Try deleting your _build-*_ folder recompiling from scratch. If the QCP errors still appear, please edit your question to provide more info: For QCustomPlot, are you using `QCUSTOMPLOT_COMPILE_LIBRARY`/_qcustomplot.dll_ or not?

Comment: I tried using the msvc2013 32 & 64 bit compilers, with no success. I also tried using Qt 5.8 rather than 5.10, and that didn't change anything either.

Comment: I went into Visual Studio -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online -> Qt and installed it, and the project now compiles successfully in visual studio. I went into Qt Creator and it still won't compile there.